# OTRS-I am running it on Windows System on localhost as a test system

Tags: otrs

I am  running OTRS on Windows on localhost as a test system.Whenever I create a ticket from customer webfront I am getting this error.
Error: Need ArticleTypeID!

Comment:
Traceback:
ERROR: OTRS-CGI-10 Perl: 5.12.3 OS: MSWin32 Time: Sun Jan 20 13:13:30 2013

Message: Need ArticleTypeID!

RemoteAddress: 127.0.0.1
 RequestURI: /otrs/customer.pl

Answer (score 0):

I think you somehow changed this value:  Ticket::Frontend::CustomerTicketMessage###ArticleType  to something that does not exist in the database.

Navigate to Admin > SysConfig > Ticket > Frontend::Customer::Ticket::ViewNew and reset the value using the circular arrow.